# Is there an easier way to make many inputs equal one?

Tags: javascript

Ok so at the moment I'm writing a script where you have to put how often something happens and the script I've used "Monthly" to signify once a month.
But obviously people might not just right "Monthly".

So I've written this to just in case they write something else.

```
if (RepeatDay === "once a month" || RepeatDay === "Once a Month" || RepeatDay === "every month" || RepeatDay === "month" || RepeatDay === "Month" || RepeatDay === "monthly"|| RepeatDay === "Once A Month"){
    var RepeatDay = "Monthly"
}
```

The thing is I have many of these types of inputs and I was wondering if there's an easier way to do it.

Comment: You're giving them free reign to enter the period? Why not just give them a drop down menu of choices?

Comment: As j0 commented. Force them to use dropdown... Otherwise you will be dealing with infinite user input posibilities. What if they dont use The word month but just "M" or if they put another weird value?

Comment: Because I also want them to be able to enter the amount of days and if I did a dropdown menu with 1 - 31 then the word Monthly at the bottom it'd probably look a bit strange.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: Entering time periods is a common operation, and _nobody_ accepts free form input. Your objection is based on a too-simple idea of how to do it; look at the appointment function in your computer (or smart phone) for some ideas.

Comment: the var inside the if will be broke the code. Be sure you remove it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can create an Array

```
var arr=["once a month","Once a Month","every month","month" ,"Month","monthly","Once A Month"]

if(arr.indexOf(RepeatDay)!==-1){
     RepeatDay='monthly';
}
```

**NOTE** : [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) does not work in IE<9 so you need to do it the classic way

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]===RepeatDay){
        RepeatDay="monthly";
        break;   //no need to check for further after a match is found
    }
}
```

Comment: lol, so complicated? Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30956960) :)

Comment: @nicael that will return true for many unwanted values as that is working just by searching for a subsequence "month"

Comment: @Anonymous the code is so obvoius why do you need to test it

Comment: @Anonymous well that happens sometimes :)

Comment: This was actually what I was looking for. I don't know why but an array didn't occur to me thanks :D

Comment: Boby this could work. But is not scalable enough. Take a look at my answer that explain why

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
if(RepeatDay.toLowerCase().indexof('month')>-1){
    var RepeatDay = "Monthly";
}
```

But as suggested in comments, it would be better to give user dropdown instead of text input in such scenario

Comment: `"four times a month"`

Comment: @MatthewMcveigh If you see OP wants to capture such strings. Those ones mentioned in the question are not the only ones he wants to capture. He mentioned, **But obviously people might not just right "Monthly".

So I've written this to just in case they write something else.** . And ideally as suggested in comments, fixed value inputs such as dropdowns would be preferable in such scenario.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, I would strongly recommend letting the user choose from a set of options you control.

If you really want to check against a list like that, though, you have several options (all most likely combined with `toLowerCase` to reduce the number of things you have to test):

1. You can use an array [as Ankit demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30956983/157247).
2. You can use a `switch` statement, which also lets you easily map other values like "weekly" and such:

   ```
   switch (RepeatDay.toLowerCase()) {
       case "once a month";
       case "every month";
       case "month";
       case "monthly":
           RepeatDay = "Monthly"
           break;
       case "weekly":
       case "once a week":
           RepeatDay = "Weekly";
           break;
       // ...
   }
   ```
3. You can use an object as a map, which again makes it easy to map "weekly" and such as well:

   ```
   var repeatOptions = {
       "once a month": "Monthly",
       "every month": "Monthly",
       "month": "Monthly",
       "monthly": "Monthly",
       "weekly": "Weekly",
       "once a week": "Weekly",
       // ...
   };
   ```

   ...then:

   ```
   RepeatDay = repeatOptions[RepeatDay.toLowerCase()];
   if (!RepeatDay) {
       // Invalid option specified
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to you to think in a different way to collect the user input data.

A dropdown with options will be more usefull for you and for the users.

The other answers could work. But think that the user still need to enter values an figure that they need to add certain words so the input work as expected. You will end with a lot of unnesesary explanatories messages or validations in the code.

Dont know your exact propose but a dropdown to select between the type of interval (monthly, weekly, yearly, daily) and aan input of type number to know the numbers of times that happen during that type of interval should work and would be more intuitive.

For mi this are valid values that you need to take care of.

( x is a random number of times )

xper month

xm

x for month

x times

x M

Every 10th

Once m

First mmonday of each m

Only in june

And so on...

You dont want an array of thousand of cases and obviously you cant validate that the word month or word m exists ( see exaples again).